# Put while loops in a method

Tags: c#, validation

Is there a way to put the while loops that are inside of the `AddToStock` method into a separate `ValidateInput` method? I have attached the `ReadInteger` code as well. (Similar to ReadDecimal/ReadString/ReadDate)

AddToStock code:

```
private static void AddToStock()
{
    //Get item id
    int itemid = ReadInteger("\nItem ID:");

    //Confirm item id is greater than 0
    while (itemid <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Item ID Cannot Be Less Than 1, Please Try Again");
        //Get item id
        itemid = ReadInteger("Item ID:");
    }

    //Get item name
    string itemname = ReadString("Item Name:");

    //While item name input empty
    while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(itemname))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You Didn't Enter An Item Name, Please Try Again");
        itemname = ReadString("Item Name:");
    }

    //Get item quantity
    int itemquantity = ReadInteger("Quantity:");

    //Confirm item quantity is greater than 0
    while (itemquantity <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Quantity Cannot Be Less Than 1, Please Try Again");
        //Get item quantity
        itemquantity = ReadInteger("Quantity:");
    }

    //Get item price
    decimal itemprice = ReadDecimal("Price Paid:");

    //Confirm item price is greater than 0
    while (itemprice <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Item Price Cannot Be Less Than Or Equal To £0.00, Please Try Again");
        //Get item price
        itemprice = ReadDecimal("Item Price:");
    }

    //Get item date added
    DateTime itemdate = ReadDate("Date Added:");
    //Add item to stock
    Employee_UI.AddToStock(itemid, itemname, itemprice, itemquantity, itemdate);
    Console.WriteLine("\nItem Added To Stock!");
}
```

ReadInteger code:

```
private static int ReadInteger(string prompt)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        try
        {
            Console.Write("> ");
            return Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        //If input not integer
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Couldn't Understand That As A Number, Please Try Again");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated! Still new to all of this :)

Comment: why do you want to do that? you can just copy the code into a new function or use the refactoring command in visual studio

Comment: You cannot make a single pure generic method that will test all cases. If you had ValidateInput<T>, how can you test if T < 0 but also string.IsNullOrWhitespace(T). You can create functions for each type and reuse them, eg ValidateString, ValidateInt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to create an additional method. You can simply modify your `ReadInteger` method to check if the input integer is in range.

Note: Instead of using `Convert.ToInt32()` and catching an exception, it's better to follow the standard way, that is, to use the [`int.TryParse()`](http://Int32.TryParse) method.

Try something like this:

```
private static int ReadInteger(string prompt, int minimum = int.MinValue)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        Console.Write("> ");

        int value;
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Couldn't Understand That As A Number, Please Try Again");
        }
        else if (value < minimum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The number Cannot Be Less Than {minimum}. Please Try Again");
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
int itemid = ReadInteger("\nItem ID:", minimum: 1);
```

You may then follow the same logic for the other `ReadXXXX` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Good idea to separate content validation from content format errors. If you want a separation between content validation and input, I would go as follows.. just separate the validation completely, in a static class. In the class you can test the type you want to validate in a generic way.. when the conditions for all fields of the same type are similar, something like

```
public static class StockInputFieldValidator
{
    public static bool ValidateItem<T>(object o)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) return ((int) o > 0);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(float)) return ((float) o > 0);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(decimal)) return ((decimal) o > 0);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string) o);
        return true;
    }
}

public static class ValidatedStockInputReader
{
    static void ReadItem(string caption, out string s)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(caption + ">");
            string result = Console.ReadLine();
            if (StockInputFieldValidator.ValidateItem<string>(result))
            {
                s = result;
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Please provide valid "+result?.GetType().Name+ " input for " + caption);
        }
    }

    static void ReadItem(string caption, out DateTime s)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(caption + ">");
            if (DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out DateTime result))
                if (StockInputFieldValidator.ValidateItem<DateTime>(result))
                {
                    s = result;
                    return;
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Invalid value for " + caption);
            Console.WriteLine("Please provide valid "+ result.GetType().Name+" input for " + caption);
        }
    }

    static void ReadItem(string caption, out int s)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(caption + ">");
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
                if (StockInputFieldValidator.ValidateItem<int>(result))
                {
                    s = result;
                    return;
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Invalid value for " + caption);
            Console.WriteLine("Please provide valid " + result.GetType().Name + " input for " + caption);
        }
    }

    static void ReadItem(string caption, out decimal s)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(caption + ">");
            if (decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out decimal result))
                if (StockInputFieldValidator.ValidateItem<decimal>(result))
                {
                    s = result;
                    return;
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Invalid value for " + caption);
            Console.WriteLine("Please provide valid " + result.GetType().Name + " input for " + caption);
        }
    }

    public static void GetStockInput(out int citemid, out string citemname, out int citemquantity, out decimal citemprice, out DateTime citemdate)
    {
        ReadItem("Item ID:", out  citemid);
        Console.WriteLine("Input was itemid=" + citemid);
        ReadItem("Item Name:", out  citemname);
        Console.WriteLine("Input was itemname=" + citemname);
        ReadItem("Quantity:", out  citemquantity);
        Console.WriteLine("Input was quantity=" + citemquantity);
        ReadItem("Price:", out  citemprice);
        Console.WriteLine("Input was itempricepaid=" + citemprice);
        ReadItem("Date:", out  citemdate);
        Console.WriteLine("Input was itemdatetime=" + citemdate);
    }
}
```